# Powershell script only converting last sAmAccountname to name

Tags: powershell

just wrote a quick script below to convert samaccountname to name. But it ONLY converts the last samaccountname in the list. Why? What am i doing wrong?

```
$Users = Get-Content .\tempuser.txt
$results = @()
foreach($User in $Users)
{
  $result = Get-ADUser -Identity $User | select name, Samaccountname
}
$result | out-file .\Test12.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the following line by adding a plus:

```
$result += Get-ADUser -Identity $User | select name,Samaccountname
```

Comment: Now it outputs nothing

Comment: That's because you have initialized the array as $results instead of $result

Comment: Yes!! That was it! Thanks a TONN!

Answer (score 0):

create a new array with predefined size.

```
$result = new-object object[] $Users.Length
for($i=0; $i -lt $Users.Length; $i++)
{
  $result[$i] = Get-ADUser -Identity $User | select name,Samaccountname
}
```